# Загрузка данных в R

Tags: r

Здраствуйте. Имеется таблица в .csv с заголовком. Но разделителя в конце заголовка не хватает. Ситуацию можно исправить, отрыв таблицу в блокноте и дописав вручную ";". А дальнейшие строки таблицы уже имеют в конце разделитель. Как можно автоматизировать процесс постановки разделятея в конце шапки.

При загрузке таблицы выдется ошибка. То есть выглядит это так:

> data <- read.table("table.csv", header = T, sep =";", dec = ".")
>
> Error in read.table("table.csv", header = T, sep =";", dec = ".")
>     повторяющиеся 'row.names' не разрешаются

Сама таблица при открытии в блокноте имеет следующий вид

col1;col2;col3;col4

1;2;3;4;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Вас проблема не в разделителе в конце первой строки, а в том, что в двух строках имеются только их переносы без данных. Судя по приведенному фрагменту: 2-я и 4-я строки.

Для примера файл в редакторе Far:

[image: Edit a.csv in Far editor]

Описанную ошибку удается получить только в случае использования `blank.lines.skip = FALSE`(не игнорировать пустые строки).

```
fl <- "D:\\-DtF\\a.csv"
data <- read.table(fl, header = T, sep =";", dec = ".", blank.lines.skip = FALSE )
```

Результат:

> Error in read.table(fl, header = T, sep = ";", dec = ".", blank.lines.skip = FALSE) : 
>     повторяющиеся 'row.names' не разрешаются

При значении `blank.lines.skip = TRUE` команда успешно отрабатывает и в результат получаем:

[image: result work blank.lines.skip = TRUE]

> NA

Причина отсутствия в конце 1-ой строки разделителя **;**

Для исключения потерь данных используйте:

```
data <- read.table(fl, header = F, sep =";", dec = ".", skip =1, blank.lines.skip = TRUE)
```

header = F - не считываете первую строку заголовков
skip =1 - пропускаете вторую пустую строку

в результате получаем:

[image: result]